# Django Debug Toolbar 1.10 (and 1.10.1) Not Showing

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

I've got django-debug-toolbar 1.9.1 working fine in my configuration (Django 2.1.2), but if I simply update it to 1.10 or 1.10.1, without changing anything else, it doesn't show up anymore. I don't see anything in the change logs that indicate I need to update any settings.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Or there a way I can turn on some kind of logging to see where it's not working?

Thanks!

Comment: Check the console in your browser's developer tools for any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/issues/1101) on GitHub was solved by refreshing the browser cache.

Try running `manage.py collectstatic` and refresh your browser cache, to make sure you aren't running javascript from an old version.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when running 'manage.py runserver'. All I had to do is Refresh my browser cache. In Chrome, you just open `View/Developer/Developer Tools` and now right click the "Refresh" button and click 'Empty Cache and Hard Reload'.

That did it for me (using Chrome), same thing under Chromium. Cheers!